# Display Array in local using React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs and want to learn more about it. As of now, i'm facing an issue where i want to groupBy using lodash and displaying it into the local:3000. When I run the js file, it gives an error saying

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {groups}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

Here is my app.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Hotel from '../data/test.json';
import _ from 'lodash';
import './App.css';

const groups = _.groupBy(Hotel, 'roomTypeLabel');
console.log(groups);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {groups}
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your code:- `<div>{groups}</div>` in render like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Hotel from '../data/test.json';
import _ from 'lodash';
import './App.css';

const groups = _.groupBy(Hotel, 'roomTypeLabel');
console.log(groups);

class App extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
            {groups}
          </div>
       );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to wrap `groups` variable into a parent element. Adjacent elements **must be** wrapped in React.

```
return (
   <div>
      {groups}
   </div>
);
```

Secondly - `_.groupBy` returns an object. You can't render explicitly an object in React. You have to change it into an array. Are you sure that you wanted to use `_.groupBy` function?

Comment: So my test.json file have multiple 'roomTypeLabel' and i want to group them into one. From that data, I want to display the different prices, ex: Double Bed Room : USD30, USD 40, USD 50. What should I type in to display in that way if _.groupBy doesnt work?

Comment: @JohnStefan I can't help you anymore since I don't know how your data looks like. Provide it in your question for further analysis.

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/17bi3c . This is how my test.json file looks like. Hope this helps on visualizing on what I'm trying to achieve.